# Таблицы и циклы

Tags: javascript, табличная-верстка

У меня не получается написать программу, выводящую на экран таблицу, в которой количество строк и столбцов задается пользователем. В каждой ячейке выводится ее порядковый номер.

Comment: А какой код есть у вас?

Comment: что иманно не получаеться ?

Comment: Если не знаете с чего начать - начните с поиска "вложенных циклов", там как раз зачастую такие задачи в пример приводятся.

Comment: Знаете, зачастую с помощью гугла ответ можно получить гораздо быстрее чем тут.   https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&dcr=1&ei=BI94WprsN4nJsQH2i5DIDA&q=Js+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83&oq=Js+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..0.207267.209116.0.210290.7.7.0.0.0.0.215.1356.0j5j2.7.0....0...1c.1j4.64.mobile-gws-serp..0.7.1354...0i7i30k1j0i8i7i30k1j0i13k1.0.itaQl4NALOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
'use strict';

let table = document.createElement('table');
let count = 1;

let rows = prompt('Сколько строк создать в таблице?', 0);
let cols = prompt('Сколько столбцов создать в таблице?', 0);

for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  table.append(tr);

  for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    let td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = count;
    count++;
    tr.append(td);
  }
}

document.body.append(table);
```

пиши если что непонятно...

Comment: а как такую сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1051611/%d0%a1%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83?noredirect=1#comment1796877_1051611

Comment: @Bloom ссылка нерабочая

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cRGynmC0

Comment: @Bloom ну а в чем проблема то?

Comment: не знаю как всё сделать с  rowspan там переодичность